# update classic ASP website MS access database

Tags: database, ms-access-2010, web-hosting

I have a very simple basic website written in classic asp which feeds of a MS access database hosted on godaddy - the site itself has very little traffic.

Each time I need to do a database update, I currently use FTP and overwrite the previous version whic works OK!

However this causes the website to crash and to get it back up and running I need to go into the godaddy hosting options and run the "Recycle your application pool" option.

Is there a more efficient way of refreshing the data without migrating the website and/or DB to avoid this crash?! Maybe some sort of an import?

cheers

Jay

Comment: Hmm... It is quite weird. It shouldn't make your site crash when you updated your db or your application. You might need to contact their support about this issue.

Comment: Still stuggling with this 2 years later ... any ideas on why an access database refresh on the godaddy site will cause the site written in classic asp to fall over?

Answer (score 0):

This has taken a long long time and we have not solved it yet but got close to finding the root cause of the problem! Sharing here in case anyone has a similar problem ... it seems that once we ran the script to upload the local database copy to the webserver we never closed the FTP connection! If you use cuteFTP to record the vbs macro the close connection post upload does not get stored. So the connection remains open until it timesout. Randomly this will keep the file locked and crash the site. The question is now how to insert some delay in the vbs macro!